# For loops on whole data sets

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, tidyverse, repeat

I am trying to preform `tidyverse` actions in a for loop on data frames in R. I would like each data frame to go through the loop and return the "clean" data frame. I know I am missing something simple. here is my code:

```
AY14<- data.frame(X1=seq(1,30,by=1), txt_student_id=sample(seq(300,329,by=1),size=30,replace=T), txt_college_name= sample(c("A","B","C","D"),size=30,replace=T,prob=c(.5,.3,.15,.05)), txt_registration_status_code=sample(c("First-time, Freshman","First-time, Transfer","Continuing"),size=30,replace=T, prob=c(.4,.1,.5)))

AY15<- data.frame(X1=seq(1,30,by=1), txt_student_id=sample(seq(300,329,by=1),size=30,replace=T), txt_college_name= sample(c("A","B","C","D"),size=30,replace=T,prob=c(.5,.3,.15,.05)), txt_registration_status_code=sample(c("First-time, Freshman","First-time, Transfer","Continuing"),size=30,replace=T, prob=c(.4,.1,.5)))

AY16<- data.frame(X1=seq(1,30,by=1), txt_student_id=sample(seq(300,329,by=1),size=30,replace=T), txt_college_name= sample(c("A","B","C","D"),size=30,replace=T,prob=c(.5,.3,.15,.05)), txt_registration_status_code=sample(c("First-time, Freshman","First-time, Transfer","Continuing"),size=30,replace=T, prob=c(.4,.1,.5)))

Dat_list <- list(AY14,AY15,AY16)

for(i in Dat_list){
  Dat_list[i]<- i %>%
    distinct(txt_student_id, txt_college_name,.keep_all = T) %>% 
    filter(txt_registration_status_code %in% list("First-time, Freshman","First-time, Transfer")) %>% 
    select(txt_student_ssn,txt_college_name,txt_registration_status_code)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version using `lapply`.

```
Dat_list <- lapply(Dat_list, function(x) {
    x %>%
      distinct(txt_student_id, txt_college_name,.keep_all = T) %>% 
      filter(txt_registration_status_code %in% list("First-time, Freshman","First-time, Transfer")) %>% 
      select(txt_college_name,txt_registration_status_code)
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It is better if you move in the loop using a numerical index. Also in the case of lists is a practical way to use indexing with `[[]]`. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
AY14<- data.frame(X1=seq(1,30,by=1), txt_student_id=sample(seq(300,329,by=1),size=30,replace=T), txt_college_name= sample(c("A","B","C","D"),size=30,replace=T,prob=c(.5,.3,.15,.05)), txt_registration_status_code=sample(c("First-time, Freshman","First-time, Transfer","Continuing"),size=30,replace=T, prob=c(.4,.1,.5)))
AY15<- data.frame(X1=seq(1,30,by=1), txt_student_id=sample(seq(300,329,by=1),size=30,replace=T), txt_college_name= sample(c("A","B","C","D"),size=30,replace=T,prob=c(.5,.3,.15,.05)), txt_registration_status_code=sample(c("First-time, Freshman","First-time, Transfer","Continuing"),size=30,replace=T, prob=c(.4,.1,.5)))
AY16<- data.frame(X1=seq(1,30,by=1), txt_student_id=sample(seq(300,329,by=1),size=30,replace=T), txt_college_name= sample(c("A","B","C","D"),size=30,replace=T,prob=c(.5,.3,.15,.05)), txt_registration_status_code=sample(c("First-time, Freshman","First-time, Transfer","Continuing"),size=30,replace=T, prob=c(.4,.1,.5)))
#List
Dat_list <- list(AY14,AY15,AY16)
#Loop
for(i in 1:length(Dat_list)){
  Dat_list[[i]]<- Dat_list[[i]] %>%
    distinct(txt_student_id, txt_college_name,.keep_all = T) %>% 
    filter(txt_registration_status_code %in% list("First-time, Freshman","First-time, Transfer")) %>% 
    select(txt_college_name,txt_registration_status_code)
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Duck, it's returning 0 rows for each data frames in the list?

Comment: @asokol I tested with the data you shared and all dataframes have rows. Please check first with the data you shared and after that be careful with new data as some variables can not be present!

Comment: to protect the data I changed some of the variable names slightly and forgot to change them back.